# How to create a pandas DataFrame with several numpy 1d arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I've created some np.arrays to do some calculation with them. (All have the same size [100,1])
Now I want to create a pandas Dataframe and each array shoud be one column of that DF.
The Names of the arrays should be the header of the DataFrame.

In Matlab I would easily do it like that:

> Table = table(array1, array2, array3, ... );

How can I do this in Python?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah sorry I misread your question. You would need to reshape the arrays to use the syntax I provided.

Answer (score 8):

Let's say these are your arrays:

```
arr1, arr2, arr3 = np.zeros((3, 100, 1))

arr1.shape
Out: (100, 1)
```

You can use [hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to stack them and pass the resulting 2D array to the DataFrame constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((arr1, arr2, arr3)))

df.head()
Out: 
     0    1    2
0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Or name the columns as `arr1`, `arr2`, ...:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((arr1, arr2, arr3)), 
                  columns=['arr{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(3)])
```

which gives

```
df.head()
Out: 
   arr1  arr2  arr3
0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0   0.0   0.0
2   0.0   0.0   0.0
3   0.0   0.0   0.0
4   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked well! Is it possible that the header gets the arrays names instead of 0,1,2 ?

Comment: In Python, names of the objects are just references. An object may have multiple names. Because of that there is no easy way of getting the name of a variable, say `arr1`. You can iterate over the names in `globals()` but it is not recommended. Do your variable names have a structure? If so, it is easy to build the names instead of extracting them. (Like arr1, arr2, arr3...)

Comment: Thank you. No they are real names. So i think i really need to rename them in the Dataframe then.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) for 2d array and `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([arr1, arr2, arr3], axis=1), columns= ['a','b','c'])
```